# Client-side user custom CSS single file for overriding multiple domains

Tags: css, domain-driven-design, customization, client-side

This is for using in Safari, though it could probably be used on Firefox as well. In Chrome you have to add a plugin anyway (which generally allow for custom CSS per domain), and Opera already allows this to be done without needing any CSS. But while it's for customizing on the client-side, it's also a pure CSS question. So [I'm using no plugins here](https://superuser.com/questions/120302/how-to-use-custom-live-css-on-safari-on-the-mac).

So, again, I got a custom CSS code (easily) working for all domains. Now I want to get specify CSS code for each domain. All with just 1 CSS file that's being loaded by Safari.

Over the web and googling, I've found two ways to supposedly do this, but none actually worked. They're both documented on [userstyles.com](http://userstyles.org/help/coding):

- @-moz-document domain("your-domain.com") { }. This would be perfect, since I can have several tags like that and just choose which style will be loaded for which domain. It just doesn't work.
- @namespace is quite confusing and I've tried every variation I could think of. None worked.

Comment: Firefox supports UserStyles.css.

Comment: @Slaks cool, then I should fix my comment about firefox.

Comment: I think this question will get old before finding an answer, which means it probably does not have one even today. For anyone who stumbled here, I'm guessing there is no way to do this with CSS alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari does not appear to support the `@-moz-document` rule, which would explain why that wouldn't have worked for you. In Firefox, the following stylesheet will work:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stackexchange.com"), domain("stackoverflow.com") {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

However, in Safari 5, there is an extension called [User CSS](http://code.grid.in.th/) (note: link is to the developer's website and not to a page in the Safari Extensions gallery; caveat emptor) that will allow you to apply a single user stylesheet to multiple sites. (It seems to be the rough Safari equivalent of Stylish.)

With respect to your last comment, I think you're right: there still seems to be no way to do this with only CSS.

Comment: And while our guesses is all we've got, it's all we've got. (plus that extension you pointed) :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting a `<link />` src dynamically based on the **document.domain**? If you're using javascript, that is. This will let you set the src of the link tag to **mydomain.com.css** or **myotherdomain.com.css**

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I'm not using javascript at all. Neither do I want to. ;)